# Compress map output result exception in hadoop program

Tags: java, hadoop

In Hadoop program, I tried to compress the map result, I wrote the following code:

```
conf.setBoolean("mapred.compress.map.output",true);
conf.setClass("mapred.map.output.compression.codec",GzipCodec.class,CompressionCodec.class);
```

and run it, I got the below exception, anybody know the reason?

```
WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1149103367_0001 
java.io.IOException: not a gzip file  
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.BuiltInGzipDecompressor.processBasicHeader(BuiltInGzipDecompressor.java:495)    
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.BuiltInGzipDecompressor.executeHeaderState(BuiltInGzipDecompressor.java:256)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.BuiltInGzipDecompressor.decompress(BuiltInGzipDecompressor.java:185)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:72)   
at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVLong(WritableUtils.java:308)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVInt(WritableUtils.java:329)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Reader.positionToNextRecord(IFile.java:400)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Reader.nextRawKey(IFile.java:425)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$Segment.nextRawKey(Merger.java:323)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.merge(Merger.java:613)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.merge(Merger.java:558)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger.merge(Merger.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:385)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:445)
```

today, I tested it again, I found that if the put the 2 lines before the job object was created,

```
Job job = new Job(conf, "MyCounter");
```

the error will happen, if after that, no error will occur, why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

are you using MRv1 or MRv2. If you are using MRv2 then use the following job config.

`config.setBoolean("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", true);
config.setClass("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec",GzipCodec.class,CompressionCodec.class);`

additionally you can set

`config.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type",CompressionType.NONE.toString());`

BLOCK|NONE|RECORD are three types of compression.